# Can this statement be simplified with ?? or ?. operators?

Tags: c#

I wonder whether the following can be simplified by using `??` or `?.`.

```
private static Stream OpenData(string filename)
   => Loader == null ? throw new Exception("...") : Loader.GetStream(filename);
```

Note that I don't care about readability.

Comment: If `GetStream()` will never return `null`, then it's equivalent to: `Loader?.GetStream(filename) ?? throw new Exception("...");`

Comment: You can make it shorter as @Iridium commented, but certainly not "simplify" it because it's going to be harder to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the exact same behavior as what you have with

```
private static Stream OpenData(string filename)
     => (Loader ?? throw new Exception("...")).GetStream(filename);
```

I'll leave it up to you whether this is any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are throwing an exception anyway in case of null, why not just call the method?

```
Loader.GetStream(filename);
```

it will throw null reference exception if the Loader is null, else successfully call the `GetStream` method.

on a side note - `Loader` seems like a `type` (based on the naming convention)... i will assume it is an instance variable because the compiler will prevent from comparing `type` to `null`.

Comment: A NullReferenceException should **always** be avoided, it is much harder to trace it.

Comment: How is it any harder to trace than throwing a new Exception("blah was null")? the stack trace will always be at the method where the exception was thrown. Also, isn't NullReferenceException the most accurate exception to throw if an object is null? Also there were talks of having a debug feature which would tell which object was null and not just the method (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/) . I think null reference is very appropriate for null objects.

Comment: A NRE represents a bug in the code, not expected behavior. An Exception that should be throw here would be an InvalidOperationException. It's not NULL because of some bug, it's NULL because the program is not at the state it's supposed to be (some call that loads `Loader` here)